# I can't see my created services on "kubectl services"

Tags: .net, sql-server, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm trying to dockerize an multilayered .NET API project then deploy it and SQL Server to Kubernetes. After I have created k8s folder for .yaml files, I encounter a problem.

I have files like this :

[image]

And even though I've written same commands for every .yaml files in k8s folder, when I write `kubectl get services` , I can see only two files which are **dotnetapp-mssql-cluster-ip-service** and **dotnetapp-server-cluster-ip-service** .
[image]

When I try to `kubectl create` or `kubectl apply` for other files that I can't see on the services list, it says **unchanged** .
[image]

How can I see all my files when I write `kubectl get services` ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have created a PVC, 2 services, 2 deployments, and an ingress? Based on you re-running `kubectl apply -f WebAPI/k8s/ingress-service.yaml` and Kubernetes telling you that `ingress.networking.k8s.io/dotnetapp` is unchanged.

Try run `kubectl get ingress`. Also remember that resources are not named after the files, but the property `name` set in `metadata` within each resource. So you should see an `ingress` called `dotnetapp` when running that commands.

Otherwise it seems you can see your other 2 services as expected using `kubectl get services`?

Comment: When I run `kubectl get ingress` , it returns with one `ingress` called `dotnet` . I have a problem with running my project so I thought maybe that was the case. But I think something else is causing the problem. Thanks for your help!